# How are GitHub markdown anchor links constructed?

Tags: github, markdown, anchor

From a GitHub Markdown header

```
# Söme/title-header_
```

GitHub's renderer creates the anchor

```
#sömetitle-header_
```

Apparently, spaces and `/` are removed, letters (ASCII and Unicode) are lowercased, and `-` and `_` are preserved.

Is this correct; are there other rules?

Comment: Thanks for the link. [The section on headings](https://github.github.com/gfm/#atx-headings) doesn't say anything on how to link is created. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub.com's process for converting Markdown heading text to `id=""` attributes for automatic `#fragment` links is **not defined** by any of the Markdown specifications *nor implementations*.

For example, it isn't described in the *[GitHub Flavored Markdown Spec](https://github.github.com/gfm/)*.

Instead, it's something that GitHub *do themselves privately* after initial conversion from Markdown to HTML is completed, this is described in Step 4 in [GitHub's own readme file on the topic](https://github.com/github/markup/blob/master/README.md) (emphasis mine):

> This library is the first step of a journey that every markup file in a repository goes on before it is rendered on GitHub.com:
>
> 1. `github-markup` selects an underlying library to convert the raw markup to HTML.
> 2. The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and class or id attributes.
> 3. Syntax highlighting is performed on code blocks. See github/linguist for more information about syntax highlighting.
> 4. **The HTML is passed through other filters that add special sauce, such as emoji, task lists, named anchors, CDN caching for images, and autolinking.**
> 5. The resulting HTML is rendered on GitHub.com.

`.md` / Markdown files are processed by CommonMarker + libcmark, which does not include `id=""` attribute and `#fragment` URI generation as a built-in feature, but CommonMarker's documentation actually provides a sample implementation of Markdown header `id=""` attributes for `#fragment` links [on the front-page](https://www.gjtorikian.com/commonmarker/), repeated below:

```rb
class MyHtmlRenderer < CommonMarker::HtmlRenderer
  def initialize
    super
    @headerid = 1
  end

  def header(node)
    block do
      out("<h", node.header_level, " id=\"", @headerid, "\">",
               :children, "</h", node.header_level, ">")
      @headerid += 1
    end
  end
end

# this renderer prints directly to STDOUT, instead
# of returning a string
myrenderer = MyHtmlRenderer.new
print(myrenderer.render(doc))

# Print any warnings to STDERR
renderer.warnings.each do |w|
  STDERR.write("#{w}\n")
end
```

The above above generates numeric monotonically increasing header `id=""` values, which helps prevent `id=""` collisions (though this is not a perfect solution), whereas as you've observed GitHub prefers to use the header's `textContent` as the basis for `id=""` attribute values.

...which means that GitHub is simply *doing their own thing* when it comes to generating `id=""` attributes, and there is no published specification for whatever transformation GitHub is using.

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives me quite some mileage:

```py
lower=header.strip().lower().replace(" ","-")
anchor=""
for c in lower:
  if c.isalnum() or c in "-_":
     anchor+=c
```